# Ubunutu - .ssh folder exists but I cannot see it? only through terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, invisible

When I go to my terminals and use $ cd ~/.ssh I am able to enter the directory, which proves it exists. However, when I use any other file browser, I cannot find the .ssh folder!

Why is this happening?? I desperately need to access the .ssh perhaps it is invisible? Can anyone help me

(Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any files or directories which start with dot are hidden. They cannot be seen from file browser. Open you terminal and

```
ls -a
```

now you will see your .ssh directory listed. make sure you are using ls -a command in the right home directory. If you able to cd ~ssh from one user then use ls -a command in the that user's home directory.

If you really want to see the files in the file browser then create a directory without starting with a dot and copy all the contents from the .ssh directory to the new directory which you have created.

```
sudo mkdir /home/user_name/sshfolder
sudo cp /home/user_name/.ssh/* /home/user_name/sshfolder/
```

Now open you file system browser and verify the contents.
I hope this is helpful.

Comment: File managers usually have an option to turn on/off display of hidden files and folders. Copying files around just to show them is not a good practice.

Comment: WOW ok this makes sense. I was using terminal as a workaround but now I know what the issue is. thank you!

Answer (score 12):

By convention, files starting with `.` are hidden. You can see them on the command line with `ls -a` or `ls -A`, 
or in your file manager by finding the setting that allows you to see "hidden" files (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>).